# Adding a <strong> Tag to the typed letters in Autocomplete field in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, autocomplete

I'm still learning React and doing some small exercises to improve my skill. it may seems easy but I'm stuck on it. As the title says, how to add a `<strong>` Tag to the typed letters to make them **bold** in auto complete field?

Here is my closest working try:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import suggestionsArray from "./suggestionsArray"; // just an array with country names

const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;

    if (value.length > 0) {
      const matchList = suggestionsArray.filter(
        item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === 0
      );
    } else {
      setMatches([]);
    }
    setInputValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="suggestions">
        <input
          placeholder="Country"
          value={inputValue}
          name="suggestionsInput"
          type="search"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <div>
          <ul className="suggestionList">
            {matches.map(item => {
              const regex = new RegExp(inputValue, "i");
              const letter = item.replace(
                regex,
                `<strong>${inputValue}</strong>`
              );
              return (
                <li key={item}>
                  <strong>{letter}</strong>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you may guessed, This kinda works but the output is printed "as is" as `HTML` Tag:

```html
<strong>d</strong>enmark
```

Where it suppose to be **d**enmark

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-autocomplete-im75f) link

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific on what problem you had during adding the `strong`? Cause it seems normal at this moment by the demo.

Comment: Hi @keikai the problem is that the output is printed "as is", I couldn't parse the `<strong>` to be like **d**enmark. Thank you.

Comment: Try [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)  Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xv40xxqze)

Comment: Thanks @awran5 but I'm a bit confused about how this works?

Comment: Hi @awran5 I just saw your answer's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60770790/autocomplete-middle-of-the-text-not-only-on-start) and this is almost what I need but in React. Can you please help me to do it?

Comment: Please check my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) It's like a React replacement for `innerHTML`

Just replace your map **return**

```js
...
const letter = item.replace(regex, `<strong>${inputValue}</strong>`);
   return <li key={item}>{letter}</li>;
...
```

**With:**

```js
...
const letter = item.replace(regex, `<strong>${inputValue}</strong>`)
   return (
     <li key={item}>
       <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: letter }} />
     </li>
   )
...
```

Here is a [codeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-autocomplete-3uklq) example.